# Is there a less hacky way of requesting a specific audio file through PHP than this?

Tags: javascript, php, html, audio

I need an audio file from the output of a php script to be placed into the source of a HTML audio tag. I can't specify which as I can't add POST variables so I do so by setting the SESSION "songRequested" through an ajax call and then requesting the file and using the session variable to specify which file is necessary.

HTML

```
<audio id ="player">
    <source src="" id = "source">
</audio>
```

JS

```
$.post('includes/songrequest.php',{'request':songName},function(){
$('#source').attr("src","includes/songrequest.php");
    player.load();
    player.play();
});
//Declare the session variable as the file you want and set the audio source to be the songrequest php below with the session variable as the file to be downloaded.
```

PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['u_uid'])){
    exit(); 
}
if(isset($_POST['request'])){
    $_SESSION['request'] = $_POST['request']; 
    //If requesting with post variables, set the session variable to it.
    exit(); 
}
//Otherwise, retrieve the file set as the session variable
$file = dirname(getcwd(),2)."\\users\\".$_SESSION['u_uid']."\\".$_SESSION['

header('Content-Type: audio/'.pathinfo($file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
readfile($file);
```

I had to go with this as I couldn't pass post variables when I called for a php source in the audio tag and I don't know of a way to really handle audio data natively in javascript.

Comment: What dose this mean `as I can't add POST variables` also some code of what you have now would be useful to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Added code and explained myself better, sorry.

Comment: I just want to point out that setting the post right into the session like that might lead you into some unexpected results. Let alone from a security stance you really shouldn't, you have no idea what is in request so you should be running some filters to make sure its safe to put into your application.

Comment: Yeah I will be doing so. Just a prototype for now. Either way, I hope this method won't actually be what I'll use and I find some other way to pass the filename.

Comment: If you cant add post data, then you can use `get` you can also use the URI segment of the URL, which would be like this  `$('#source').attr("src","includes/songrequest.php/{songname}");` with `{songname}` being accessible inside the `$_SERVER` supper global.  One thing to mention is for security you will want to pass just the filename, and check that there are no directory separators in the filename supplied / and \ as well as not starts with a `.`, which will prevent directory transversial

Comment: Better yet would be to use something other then a filename, such as an ID or some kind of hash that is looked up in a database for the file path.  This prevents a wood be hacker from using the path to navigate to other folders and output important info.

Comment: Thanks! That'll work nicely. May also implement an ID but not sure if necessary as long as I clean the input.

Comment: There are a few `hash($data, $algo)` that are about 16 characters or less that would work too.  I personally prefer using hashes because then they are not chronological and harder to guess.  Even just hashing the ID works nicely than it's most likely unique as long as you have a reasonably small data set.

Comment: I just use it because someone could see  `"includes/songrequest.php/2"` and think oh whats `"includes/songrequest.php/4"` etc.  As it's easy to work out what other files would be. Mostly,  it just looks nicer to me, but I doubt it makes a real difference.

Comment: To clarify, the user should have access to all the songs in their directory anyway. User songs are split with new directories per user and they can only access their own directory. I'm not sure it's the best method but it should stop this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rally there is nothing more secure about `post` then a `get` request.  Both can be spoofed against your site.   The best way to do it if you ask me is to not use either of them, but instead use a URI segment. *I should mention this is no more secure then either post or get* the main advantage of a URI is you can still use the get and post data without muddling it up.  And when you think about it, logically it is a resource you are identifying, so using just a URL/URL makes a sort of sense there.

URI is the part of the URL that is after the "real" resources location.  An example would be

```
$('#source').attr("src","includes/songrequest.php/{songname}‌​");
```

Where `{songname}` is the request URI.  This is commonly used in MVC frameworks that pipe everything through a main `index.php`.  Such as `www.example.com/index.php/some_controller/some_method`.  Often this is fact is hidden by rewriting the URL with mod_rewrite ( HTACCESS ).

Now to access that data you can look in the `$_SERVER` Super Global, where it should be something like `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` ( I forget off the top of my head ).  You may have to trim some slashes off or clean it up a bit..

Now as to the content of that data.  I would suggest not even passing a filename, just a hash or ID or songname etc.   Then you use that to look up the actual path.  This will prevent paths being used that you don't want, as the path comes from an internal data source that is looked up by that "piece" of data you are passing.

So you would pass something like this ( if using a pretty hash )

```
$('#source').attr("src","includes/songrequest.php/2Bzi0U8t");
```

Then you look up that value in the DB, get the URL and off you go.

Also I don't think there is anything inherently wrong with just doing this

```
$('#source').attr("src","includes/songrequest.php?song=2Bzi0U8t");
```

The key here is to not pass an actual path, because that could be exploited by directory transversal.  Which, is where a hacker supplies something like this as the path

```
song=../../../somefile_we_dont_want_a_hacker_accessing.txt
```

Basically it allows them to navigate around on the file system and access things they shouldn't be accessing.  But by using a lookup for that the worst they could do is lookup something already stored in your DB.

Make sense.

Comment: Really appreciate the help! Thanks!

Comment: Sure, glad I could help.